How can I restrict access to code on VS Code so that only I can access it and other users must log in and can only access the launched GUI?
How can I restrict the backend code on VS Code so that users can only access the launched GUI?
I have developed a GUI from some Python code I made in Jupyter Notebook via VS Code. I made and launched the GUI with the PyPanel Package and it works great. My peers have requested to use the GUI and I'm willing to share it with them as long as the backend code I've used to develop it all remains confidential and inaccessible by them (i.e. so that they are only acccessing the GUI). My current understanding is that I'd need to potentially launch a server (I believe I can do this with PyPanel) and then host it either on some computer or with something external.
I've looked into the "serving" (i.e using AWS or Azure etc.) and the ongoing monthly costs don't seem worth it to me. Is there not another way in which I can just host and serve it locally? There'll only be about 3 people (including me) using it so I don't want it to cost too much.
Ideally, I'd like the following:

The GUI can be used remotely without users seeing/accessing the
backend code.
The users who access the GUI require a sign-in/login
which administrator users can monitor and, if need be, block access.

I haven't been able to find anything online which is surprising because other much simpler softwares have security or restrictions on access such that users can only use a part of the document, I'm looking for the same thing here with VS Code; how can I restrict the backend code so that users can only access the launched GUI?

This functionality is not provided by VSCode itself.
As far as I know you can try installing the Live Share extension to achieve it.
This extension allows you to share your project in real-time with specific users who need to log in with their Microsoft or GitHub accounts.  They will be able to access the GUI but not directly access the code unless you permit them.


Thanks, I also don't want them to view the code either though so im not sure if this helps? Maybe I could liveshare a file that opens/runs the GUI?

@Hendrix13 yes, you could try it. In the settings of this extension, you could set read-only, this will allow others to run and interact with the application, but they won't be able to see or modify your code. If your GUI application can be run within a Jupyter Notebook, you can share the notebook in a way that allows interaction without revealing the underlying code.

When I tried the "read-only" mode the user was not able to run the code, only read it. Shame because this seems like a great solution.
